# Socket CLOSED after using it in a THREAD

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

This a complicated issue so I will try to be as clear as possible.
Thanks in advance for every people who read this.

I'm actualy working on a school project where I have to develop a "shot them up" game but in multiplayer.

To handle the online part, we are using a thread (from the *BOOST* library) in the client to receive the informations from the server by a socket, this is the function we are using to do this :

```cpp
void handleReceived(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket &socket, boost::array<char, 30> buf, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &sender_endpoint)
{
    std::thread ([&socket, &buf, &sender_endpoint]() {
        while (true) {
            boost::system::error_code error;
            std::size_t bytes_transferred = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buf), sender_endpoint, 0, error);
            if (!error) {
                std::string received_data(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + bytes_transferred);
                std::cout << "Data received from server: " << received_data << std::endl;
                received_data_queue.push(received_data);
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }).detach();
}
```

the socket is initialize in a main function right there :

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    const int FPS = 30;
    const int frameDelay = 1000/FPS;
    Uint32 frameStart;
    int frameTime;
    std::string server_ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int server_port = 8888;

    init(); // *Init every SDL library

    RenderWindow window("R-TYPE", 1280, 720); // *Create the window and the renderer

    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(service);
    socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint server_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(server_ip), server_port);

    while (gameRunning) // *Main game loop
    {
        frameStart = SDL_GetTicks();

        game(window, server_endpoint, socket);

        frameTime = SDL_GetTicks() - frameStart; // *Handling and setting fps to 30
        if (frameDelay > frameTime)
        {
            SDL_Delay(frameDelay - frameTime);
        }
    }
    window.cleanUp(); // *Cleaning everything up 
    SDL_Quit(); // *
    TTF_Quit(); // *
    return 0;
}
```

and as you can see I'm sending the "socket" and "the server_endpoint" value to the "game" function who is the "game loop"

PS : the code is actualy disgusting and I know it, I am just trying to find out if the way I'm doing it is the right way and then I will reorganize the code

OK, now we are going to talk about the problem :

Currently, what I'm doing is storing a string send by the server from the socket, this string being the entity and her position where I have to render her as a client.

This is the game loop function (I will explain every part dw) :

```cpp
void rtype(RenderWindow window, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &server_endpoint, boost::asio::ip::udp::socket &socket)
{
    ParallaxBackground bg(window.getRenderer(), "../assets/para1.png", "../assets/para2.png", "../assets/para3.png");
    RenderGame gpu(window.getRenderer()); // *Initializing graphics (texture..)
    
    boost::array<char, 30> buf;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
    std::string data;
    handleReceived(socket, buf, sender_endpoint); // THE THREAD
    bool running = true;
    while (running) 
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { // *Handling and waiting for events (button hit...)
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("080"), server_endpoint);
                running = false;
            }
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("0111"), server_endpoint);
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("0112"), server_endpoint);
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("0114"), server_endpoint);
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("0113"), server_endpoint);
                    break;
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("012"), server_endpoint);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(window.getRenderer());
        bg.render();
        data = getReceivedData();
        if (!data.empty()) {
            gpu.parse_entities(data); // *Parse data sent by the server
            gpu.render_entities(); // *Render entities
        }
    }
    state = 2;
}
```

It looks very complicated but it really isn't !

The thing that interests us is the "handleReceived" function (commented as THE THREAD) and the "if(!data.empty())" statement.

What am I doing here is using the handleReceived function to store the data from the server every time (by using a Thread) and then calling the "getReceivedData()" function to store the actual data in a clean std::string.
Then I'm just checking if the "data" value is empty and if she is not rendering the entity by the data.

The getReceivedData() in case :

```cpp
std::string getReceivedData()
{
    if (!received_data_queue.empty()) {
    std::string received_data = received_data_queue.front();
    received_data_queue.pop();
    return received_data;
    } 
    else 
        return("");
}
```

Now this is the problem :

Everything work normally and pretty well for the first "command" sent by the server then stored by the client

but when we are sending a second command the socket close himself right after her and then we got this message :

[Error: Socket operation on non-socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o1zP.png)

I hope I was clear enough, sorry for the language, I'm not speaking English fluently.
Here for every questions.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many instances of undefined behavior in the shown code due to improper use of core C++ fundamental concepts. Here's just one of them.

```
void handleReceived(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket &socket,
                    boost::array<char, 30> buf,
```

The `buf` parameter gets passed by value. When `handleReceived` returns `buf` gets destroyed, this is how passing parameters by value happens in C++.

```
    std::thread ([&socket, &buf, &sender_endpoint]() {
```

`buf` gets captured by reference, the thread gets detached, and `handleReceived` returns, destroying `buf`. The detached execution thread continues to run, with a reference to a destroyed object. Dereferencing `buf` results in undefined behavior.

It is also unclear what the mysterious `received_data_queue` object is, and whether it is thread-safe, despite being accessed from multiple execution threads. It looks like one of standard C++ containers, which makes it thread-unsafe, and this kind of access from multiple execution threads will result in more undefined behavior.

It is also unclear whether `socket` and `sender_endpoint` are guaranteed to exist as long as the execution thread continues to reference those objects.

The common denominator for all of the apparent issues is the lack of proper thread-safety and lifetime scope management of C++ objects. All of these issues in the shown code must be fixed before it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.
I didn't understand what I have to do to solve the buf issue, How can I fix this ?
Also, received_data_queue is an global variable "std::queue<std::string>"

Comment: and I forget but socket and sender_endpoint are variables so I think they can't really disappeared no ?

Comment: Of course they can disappear. After all, `buf` is also a variable, and it disappears when the function returns. Also: making variables global does not make them thread-safe, C++ does not work this way. It makes no difference whether a variable is global, or local, as far as thread-safety is concerned. Thread safety and object lifetimes are complex topics that are discussed, at length, in your C++ textbook. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow does not work very well as a textbook replacement, and it's not possible to fully explain them, if you're not familiar with them, in just one or two paragraphs.

Comment: Ok, well I appreciate this tips. Thanks, I will work on it.

Comment: Can you explain the reason why `buf` gets passed in, like that. What is accomplished by doing that? `buf` appears to be used only by the closure that's running the execution thread. Why does `buf` need to be declared in the calling function, passed in as a parameter, then captured by the closure? What does that do? In absence of any other motive, it seems like this might be code that's copy/pasted from somewhere else, that came back in response to a keyword search. Copy/pasting search results, without understanding how it works, and why, doesn't work very well.